# Why can you instantiate a class from a string variable but not a string in PHP?

Tags: php

How come in PHP this works:

```
$myClass = 'App\MyClass';
$object = new $myClass;
```

But this results in an error:

```
$myClass = 'MyClass';
$object = new 'App\\'.$myClass;
```

In the second example, an `unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` is thrown.

As it turns out, the above example is due to [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) since `new` takes highest precedence, but...

Similarly, I can try instantiating with just a string as in:

```
$object = new 'App\MyClass';
```

And the same error is thrown. Why is this?

Comment: .. because PHP. (This is not nearly the only syntactic edge case.)

Comment: So it's just one of those PHPisms? There is no reasoning behind it? I was thinking maybe the `new` keyword takes its arguments by reference and that's why it has to be a variable.

Comment: Because concatenation is lower [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `new`; so you're trying to instantiate a new `App\\` and then concatenate $myClass to that instance

Comment: Ok but what about just a plain old string? @MarkBaker

Comment: Well if your MyClass is actually a namespaced class, as it is in the first example, then you'll get errors

Comment: I updated my answer @MarkBaker it is the same either way

Comment: try it with parenthesis to give the string precedence.

Comment: unexpected '(' error @r3wt

Comment: @samrap then its just a limit of the lexer/parser, which is understandable given the need to quickly interpret a script and run it. would be different if the language was compiled, the lexer/parser could be much more complex.

Comment: @r3wt It *is* a limit of the lexer/parser (and the informal language specification it handles), yes. But it is *not* "understandable .. to quickly interpret a script". It is simply a syntax case; there is not reason it *couldn't* take in an arbitrary expression, although such could justifiably be prohibited within a language (so it's not a "fault" per se), as JavaScript and Python are counter-arguments.

Comment: It's simply how the new operator is defined: `T_NEW class_name_reference|new_variable ctor_arguments`. It only allows literal names, or variables, and some variable expressions, but not string expressions.

Comment: @mario i'm curious why they placed this arbitrary limitation on the language?

Comment: @r3wt PHP has an .. implementation specification. The implementation form that makes it into the lexer/parser has 'great sticking power'. And since this can be bypassed quite easily it's not a very high priority to re-examining (including if such could ever break existing code).

Comment: @r3wt That's just heritage from the simpler array/record-oriented object model in PHP3. And in practice nobody really needed more dynamic constructor expressions, so that design decision was never revisited.

Comment: @r3wt the fundamental issue are constants and function calls. That's conflicting with class name and the optional parenthesis.

Comment: @mario I will accept that as the answer if you post it as one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPs syntax is defined in [zend_language_parser.y](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y), and it simply doesn't define any more complex expressions for the [`new`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#L845) operator:

```
new_expr:
    T_NEW class_name_reference ctor_arguments
            { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_NEW, $2,  }
    |   T_NEW anonymous_class
            { $$ = $2; }
```

Where [`class_name_reference`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#L845) is:

```
class_name_reference:
        class_name      { $$ = $1; }
    |   new_variable    { $$ = $1; }
```

And [`new_variable`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#L1143) allows for a limited set of variable expressions:

```
new_variable:
        simple_variable
            { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_VAR, $1); }
    |   new_variable '[' optional_expr ']'
            { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_DIM, $1, $3); }
    |   new_variable '{' expr '}'
            { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_DIM, $1, $3); }
    |   new_variable T_OBJECT_OPERATOR property_name
            { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_PROP, $1, $3); }
    |   class_name T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM simple_variable
            { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_STATIC_PROP, $1, $3); }
    |   new_variable T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM simple_variable
            { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_STATIC_PROP, $1, $3); }
// Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies Ltd., the Zend license 2.00
```

Which is why you can't have string expressions there. (It was never extended, because the trivial instantiations and $classvarnames are often sufficient. So the allowed syntax is mostly the same as in PHP3, when it was introduced.)

Comment: I knew there was a detailed answer somewhere, thanks for showing some under-the-hood code

Answer (score 4):

The parser's implementation is not generic, therefore in some cases the parser would hiccup over things the engine could in fact handle. There (still) isn't even an official formal grammar for PHP, which makes it hard to predict things like this, without simply trying them out. It's the way of the PHP world :)

Comment: Interesting. I always thought the inconsistencies stopped with PHP's inconsistent naming conventions and argument orders. You learn something new every day!

Comment: @samrap that's just the tip of the iceberg, but i'll gladly defend this fine little language that has evolved from a pile of crap into something powerfu.

Comment: I'm not complaining, I love PHP :)

Comment: @r3wt I'll defend "what is" (ie "why things work the way they do").. I choose my languages differently, but I otherwise don't care what others choose to use .. or are paid to use.

Answer (score 4):

PHP expects a variable or name reference for object definitions, it simply won't allow strings. You can use this hack which is based on '' empty string named variable the is instantly created and used based on the fact that `${false}` evaluates to `${''}` as follows to create an object from string:

```
$obj = new ${!${''} = 'App\MyClass'}();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of operator precedence:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Since 'new' has a higher precedence than '.' it gets processed first.

As far as your code goes, what the compiler sees is:

```
$myClass = 'MyClass';
$object = new 'App\\';
$object = $object . $myClass;
```

For the second part of your question, why: `$object = new 'App\MyClass'`; doesn't work. I am unsure.

If I had to guess I would say it is because when you do `new 'App\MyClass'`, the parser doesn't know it is a string when it encounters it. Until the line has been processed it doesn't know if it is dealing with a string, number, object, etc. It could discover that and properly cast it to a string but I would guess this comes back to operator precedence where it doesn't do those type of casts until after handling the 'new' operator.

Curiously, I just tested it in Quercus PHP and it runs fine. As other people have mentioned, php isn't a fully defined language so things like this manifest as differences between implementations.

Comment: See the bottom of the question.

Comment: This answer not explain `$object = new 'App\MyClass';`

Comment: I have updated my question to be more clear on the answer I am now looking for. This is definitely part of the answer, just not all of it :)